# How to use scope functions in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two drop downs 
drop down 1

```
<select data-ng-model="item.company" ng-options="c.id as c.name for a in companylist>
  </select>
```

choosing a company value in dropdown 1 will trigger drop down 2 to populate employees from the selected company

drop down 2

```
<select data-ng-model="item.employeeid" ng-options="e.id as e.name for e in getEmployee(item.company)"></select>


 function getEmployee(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.companylist.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.companylist[i].id == id) {
                    return $scope.companylist[i].employees;                   
                }
            }
        };
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work (but I'm not sure); yet the better way would be to use `ng-change` on first drop-down change and set a scope variable which is binded with the second drop-down.

Drop-down 1-

```
<select data-ng-model="item.company" ng-change="updateEmployee(item.id)" ng-options="c.id as c.name for a in companylist>
```

Drop-down 2-

```
<select data-ng-model="item.employeeid" ng-options="e.id as e.name for e in employees"></select>
```

Code behind:

```
function updateEmployee(id) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.companylist.length; i++) {
       if ($scope.companylist[i].id == id) {
          $scope.employees = $scope.companylist[i].employees;                   
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: This would work fine. but If I restore the viewmodel, or if I assign item.employeeid =1. it would not resolve.

Comment: Sorry, didn't got you. What are you trying to say?

Comment: I am trying to reconstruct the UI based on the view model. Lets say I have the initial scope set to $scope.item={"company": 1, "employeeid":10},the ng-change will not fire and hence $scope.employees wont get set.

Comment: But that will happen just for one time when this view is loaded, right? So you can handle that by defining the `$scope.employees` to the default company

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way.. and works!!

In the dropdown2

```
<select data-ng-model="item.employeeid" >
<option ng-repeat="e in getEmployee(item.company)"
          value="{{e.id}}"
          title="{{e.name}}"
          ng-selected="e.id == item.employeeid">{{e.name}}                                                </option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function getEmployee(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.companylist.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.companylist[i].id == id) {
                    return $scope.companylist[i].employees;                   
                }
            }
        };
```